# How to flush console.log output on Windows

Tags: windows, node.js, logging, console

I have a Node.js program with a long process with some internal logging:

```
console.log(msg)
```

When I run on Windows Node.js, the message is not displayed in real time - I get a large number of messages in the same late time.

When I use "console.warn" instead of "console.log", the messages display earlier, but still not in real time.

Is there a way to tell Node.js to automatically flush the console buffer after each log message?

Comment: This is also a problem under Linux, where an unhandled exception may cause the program to terminate before all the output is visible, so you don't see the content from your most recent debugging `console.log()` statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that `console.log` is asynchronous in Windows. In linux/unix it is blocking, so it's not buffering and needing a flush, putting your `console.logs` on the event queue.

One alternative may be [process.stdout](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdout)

Edit: ok that's not a solution. Someone else may have a better solution, but you can either use one of the more comprehensive logging libraries or populate your console.log with more info that tells you when and where the log occurred so you can correlate them.